# enhanced for-loop behavior for handling collection object

Tags: java

As I am learner of Java.. I came across the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
  a.add("1");
  a.add("2");
  for(String str: a){
  a = new ArrayList<>();
  System.out.println(str);
  }
 }
```

I guessed the answer to be

> 1 
>   null  (since the reference is now pointing another object)

but the answer is

> 1
>   2

I am unable understand the behavior of enhanced for loop here.

Comment: Have you tried `System.out.println(a);` just after `System.out.println(str);`? What does it give you? You are essentially looping using a iterator in a for each.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: Yes , i tried that  it is giving '[]' as output....what does '[]' indicates @AniketSahrawat

Comment: @NamrataShukla It means `a` is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enhanced for loop creates an `Iterator` to iterate of the elements of your `ArrayList`. Changing the `a` reference to refer to a new `ArrayList` doesn't affect the `Iterator` that was created by the loop.

Your loop is equivalent to

```
Iterator<String> iter = a.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String str = iter.next();
    a = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run

```
for(String str: a)
```

It gets an iterator from `a`, then iterates using that iterator. Reassigning `a` after it has the iterator will have no effect since it isn't using the `a` reference, it's using the iterator that `a` returned when the loop started.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, enhanced for loop uses iterator. So changing the reference will not have any impact.
You can check different scenarios [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)